# Bind another dropdowns as per previous values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have total 4 dropdowns list... all dropdown contain numbers.

The maximum number of the last three dropdowns together is **always equal to the amount that’s selected in the 1st dropdown**.

```
If user selected 4 from 1st dropdown.

In this case all remaining dropdowns contain the values 0, 1, 2 ,3 and 4.

If customer selects 2 from 2nd dropdown then other two dropdowns will only show the values 0,1 and 2.

If customer selects 1 from 3rd dropdown then last should only show the values 0 and 1.
```

can anyone help me to sort-out this. Thanks in advance

I have tried so far

```
var tripChildSelect = $('#trip-child-count-range_0');
        var childRangeLength = "<?php echo $this->getChildRangeLength()?>";
        var j;

        for(j=1; j <= childRangeLength; j++ )
        {
            var childRange = $('#trip-child-count-range_' + j);
        }

        tripChildSelect.change(function() {
            tripChildSelect = $(this);
            availableChildren = tripChildSelect.data('max-count') - tripChildSelect.val();
            console.log(tripChildSelect.data('max-count') - tripChildSelect.val());
            if(tripChildSelect.data('max-count') - tripChildSelect.val() === 0) {
                for(j=1; j <= childRangeLength; j++ )
                {
                    var childRange = $('#trip-child-count-range_' + j);
                    childRange.prop('disabled', true);
                }
            } else {
                for(j=1; j <= childRangeLength; j++ )
                {
                    var childRange = $('#trip-child-count-range_' + j);
                    childRange.find('option').each(function (index, element) {
                        selectOption = $(element);
                        if(selectOption.val() <= availableChildren) {
                            selectOption.show();
                        } else {
                            selectOption.hide();
                        }
                    });
                    childRange.prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        }); 

        //disable if sum equals
        $('.trip-child-count-range').change(function() {
            // body...
            var sum = 0;
            $('.trip-child-count-range :selected').each(function() {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
            });
           // console.log('sum- '+sum);
            if(sum == $('#trip-child-count').val())
            {
                $('.trip-child-count-range').each(function() {
                    if($(this).val() == 0)
                        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $('.trip-child-count-range').each(function() {
                    if($(this).val() == 0)
                        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
                });
            }
          })

$('#trip-child-count').change(function() {
            // body...
            var i;
            for (i = 1; i <= $(this).val(); i++)
            { 
                 if ( $(".trip-child-count-range option[value='"+i+"']").length == 0 )
                 $('.trip-child-count-range').append( '<option value="'+i+'">'+''+i+'</option>' );
            }
            //set adta-max-xount
            $('#trip-child-count-range_0').data( "max-count", $(this).val());
           // console.log('hello' + $('#trip-child-count-range_0').data( "max-count"));

            //remove greater options
            $(".trip-child-count-range  option").each(function() {
                if($(this).val() > $('#trip-child-count').val()) 
                {
                    $(".trip-child-count-range option[value="+this.value+"]").remove();
                }
            });


            //added finalllu
            $('.trip-child-count-range').attr('disabled', false);
            $('.trip-child-count-range option[value=0]').attr('selected','selected');
            availableChildren = $('#trip-child-count').val();
        });
```

first dropdown id : **#trip-child-count**

common class for remaining 3 dropdowns: **trip-child-count-range**

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Comment: @RJParikh... see my question again, I just added my code

Comment: Ok, Add this code with HTML in code snippet of stackoverflow so we can check and resolve in your code

Answer (score 0):

Here I put your basic need. First create first drop down with 0-4 options and make other three drop down as empty. Then append options to other drop down based on the current drop down value

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <select id="dropdown1">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select id="dropdown2">         
            </select>
            <select id="dropdown3">
            </select>
            <select id="dropdown4">
            </select>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {            
               $("#dropdown1").on("change",function(){
                var dd1 = parseInt($(this).val());
                $("#dropdown2, #dropdown3, #dropdown4").empty();
                for(var i=0;i<=dd1;i++){
                    $("#dropdown2, #dropdown3, #dropdown4").append('<option val='+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
                }               
              });

              $("#dropdown2").on("change",function(){
                var dd1 = parseInt($("#dropdown1").val());
                var dd2 = parseInt($(this).val());              
                $("#dropdown3, #dropdown4").empty();
                for(var i=0;i<=dd1-dd2;i++){
                    $("#dropdown3, #dropdown4").append('<option val='+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
                }               
              });

              $("#dropdown3").on("change",function(){
                var dd2 = parseInt($("#dropdown2").val());
                var dd3 = parseInt($(this).val());
                $("#dropdown4").empty();
                for(var i=0;i<=dd2-dd3;i++){
                    $("#dropdown4").append('<option val='+i+'>'+i+'</option>');
                }               
              });
            });    
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but I want
The maximum number of the last three dropdowns together is always equal to the amount that’s selected in the 1st dropdown.
if you select 4 from first then user can select 0,1,2,3,4 from 2nd
and if user select 3 from 2nd then 3rd dropdown will only have 0 and 1
it should be always sum of 1st dropdown

Comment: So the near by drop down should have value based on the previous one then others should be empty.

Comment: So you need to monitor both total sum of other drop downs value with first one and update near by drop down based on the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for answer...
its not properly working...
try this sequence... 
1st -> 3
2nd -> 2
3rd -> 1
so sum is complete here.. but still 4th one showing 1 value in dropdown... it should be disabled. Thanks again